# Using variables in a database

Tags: database, prolog

I use SWI-Prolog.
It is impossible?

```
:- dynamic question/1.
   question([do, you, know, what, a, F1, is, ?]).
   question([does, F1, have, a, F2, ?]).

.....

 ?- question([do, you, know, what, a, son,  is, ?]), writeln(F1).
F1 = son.
```

Comment: Please note that the scope of `F1` is limited to the clause it occurs in. So the `F1` in the query is different to the `F1` in the fact. You would need some extra context information to manage this. For a beginner, just take it that it's not possible.

Comment: Overall, what is it you are wanting to achieve or do? You could do something like, `question([do, you, know, what, a, F1, is, ?], [F1]).` and `question([does, F1, have, a, F2, ?], [F1, F2]).` and thus capture the variable names in the same clause. Then a query like, `question([do, you, know, what, a, son,  is, ?], L).` would yield, `L = [son]`.

Comment: @lurker you should consider writing your comment as an answer

Comment: Thanks friends! I thought that my version can somehow earn.

Comment: @Boris I considered it, but I am very uncertain about what the OP's trying to achieve, so I wasn't sure it was a suitable answer.

Comment: @lurker To me it looked like a misunderstanding about the scope of variable names, and your comment shows exactly how to solve the problem.

Comment: @Boris ah, right, I wasn't seeing it from that perspective. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Prolog, when you have a predicate clause or fact (or rule), any variable that occurs only *once* is considered a *singleton*. That means that Prolog has no information in the clause that relates the variable to anything else and cannot instantiate it in that clause.

A fact like the following has a singleton variable, `F1`:

```
question([do, you, know, what, a, F1, is, ?]).
```

There's nothing in this fact which relates to `F1`. Thus, a query such as:

```
?- question([do, you, know, what, a, son, is, ?]).
```

will match and, thus, succeed. But there is no variable in your query that unifies with anything in the fact, so you have no other result. Likewise, `F1` and `F2` are singleton variables in the following fact:

```
question([does, F1, have, a, F2, ?]).
```

One way you can remedy this situation is to isolate the variables in a separate argument so that they are no longer singleton, and Prolog will unify them when a query is performed. For example:

```
question([do, you, know, what, a, F1, is, ?], [F1]).
question([does, F1, have, a, F2, ?], [F1, F2]).
```

Now you can do a query using your own variables which will be unified with those in these facts:

```
?- question([do, you, know, what, a, son, is, ?], [X]).
X = son
```

When Prolog receives the query, it matches your first fact, and the first argument, `[do, you, know, what, a, son, is, ?]` is unified with `[do, you, know, what, a, F1, is, ?]`, and `[X]` will be unified with `[F1]`. Since the first unification results in `F1 = son`, then you will have `[X] = [son]` and so, `X = son`.

Similarly:

```
?- question([does, fred, have, a, son, ?], [X, Y]).
X = fred
Y = son
```

Then a query like, question([do, you, know, what, a, son, is, ?], L). would yield, L = [son]